# How can I replace a word in a column without changing the width

Tags: replace, alignment

I'm writing [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#scenario-outline) example tables, which are formatted like this:

```
| title   | title  |
| data    | data   |
| data    | data   |
```

How can I replace one of the data or title cells with a word of differing length without disturbing the layout?

Comment: Use `R` to overwrite text? (and possibly add some spaces)

Comment: That's the closest I've found, seems clumsy though. Maybe I have too much faith in vim :-)

Comment: There are text alignment plugins, you could use one of those to re-align columns after an edit (e.g. "EasyAlign").

Comment: I'm actually in [VsVim](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/) which doesn't have plugins, I can switch out to full vim but it's a faff. [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) does actually re-align it all but I have to replace the last `|` to get it to fire.

Comment: Oh. Consider writing a VsVim plugin then, if possible - you'll be the hero of many Visual users :)

Comment: If you are using VsVim you should put that in your question as there are significant differences between VsVim and Vim. If you where using Vim then I would suggest an alignment plugin like [EasyAlign](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) or [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). This can be improved upon this by using [cucumbertables](https://gist.github.com/tpope/287147) or [Vim Table Mode](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode). As VanLaser suggested you can use `R`. Since SpeckFlow realigns on `|` can you do `cf|` and add your text?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out cucumbertables, looks good. I didn't mention it as I'm also interested in the pure vim answer ;-)

Comment: I have https://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber but it doesn't appear to do what I want (unless there's more to it than the readme shows)

Comment: @PeterRincker can you post the cucumbertables thing as an answer so I can mark it as accepted :-)  https://github.com/timabell/vim-cucumber-align-pipes/commit/00a1d8969bb34f0eabaac3af32a94d1fe649f320

Answer (score 3):

If you were using Vim them you could use some alignment plugin, as mentioned on the question comments. Or you could use [the vimwiki plugin](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki), which provides several helpers to use tables.

As you are using VsVim, you could try to isolate the table formatting function in [vimwiki/autoload/vimwiki/tbl.vim](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/dev/autoload/vimwiki/tbl.vim#L495) and adapt it in a VsVim plugin:

```
function! vimwiki#tbl#format(lnum, ...) "{{{
  if !(&filetype ==? 'vimwiki')
    return
  endif
  let line = getline(a:lnum)
  if !s:is_table(line)
    return
  endif

  if a:0 == 2
    let col1 = a:1
    let col2 = a:2
  else
    let col1 = 0
    let col2 = 0
  endif

  let indent = s:get_indent(a:lnum)
  if &expandtab
    let indentstring = repeat(' ', indent)
  else
    let indentstring = repeat(' ', indent / &tabstop) . repeat(' ', indent % &tabstop)
  endif

  for [lnum, row] in s:get_aligned_rows(a:lnum, col1, col2)
    let row = indentstring.row
    call setline(lnum, row)
  endfor

  let &tw = s:textwidth
endfunction "}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not aware of any plugin support for VsVim but I'll look into the full vim plugins.

Comment: @TimAbell I don't know much about VsVim, but [based on this VsVim issue](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/pull/1510) I would guess that it is possible. If you don't find clear information on the documentation you should consider opening a issue asking about it.

Comment: Cheers, that's definitely worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy paste the below functions (https://github.com/imbichie/vim-vimrc-/blob/master/MCCB_MCCE.vim) in your .vimrc or .gvimrc file and call the MCCB or MCCE function.

```
" MCCB - Move the Character to the Column from the Begin of line
" This is a function for Moving the specified Character 
" in a given range of lines to a the specified Column from the Begin of the line
" NOTE 1 :- If the specified character and the first character of the line are same
"           then the number of Occurrence (num_occr) will be one less than the actual
" NOTE 2 :- Maximum space between the specified character with in the range 
"           of lines should be less than or equal to 80, if we need more than 80
"           then we need to insert more spaces by increasing the value 80 in the 
"           "nmap s 80i <ESC>" line inside the function
" Usage :-  in command mode do it like below
" Eg 1:-    :5,11call MCCB(1, '=', 8)
"           The above command will move the 1st Occurrence from the begin of Character =
"           to the 8th Column of the lines from 5 to 11
" Eg 2 :-   :7,10call MCCB(2, '+', 12)
"           The above command will move the 2nd Occurrence of Character + to the 12th
"           Column of the lines from 7 to 10
    function! MCCB (num_occr, mv_char, col_num) range
        if (a:firstline <= a:lastline)
            nmap s 80i <ESC>
            let line_num = a:firstline
            while line_num <= a:lastline
                execute "normal " . line_num . "G0" . a:num_occr . "f" . a:mv_char . "s" . a:col_num . "|dw"
                let line_num = line_num + 1
            endwhile
            nunmap s
        else
            execute printf('ERROR : Start line %d is higher thatn End line %d, a:firstline, a:lastline)
        endif
    endfunction

" MCCE - Move the Character to the Column from the End of line
" This is a function for Moving the specified Character 
" in a given range of lines to a the specified Column from the End of the line
" NOTE 1 :- If the specified character and the last character of the line are same
"           then the number of Occurrence (num_occr) will be one less than the actual
" NOTE 2 :- Maximum space between the specified character with in the range 
"           of lines should be less than or equal to 80, if we need more than 80
"           then we need to insert more spaces by increasing the value 80 in the 
"           "nmap s 80i <ESC>" line inside the function
" Usage :-  in command mode do it like below
" Eg 1:-    :5,11call MCCE(1, ';', 20)
"           The above command will move the 1st Occurrence from the End of Character ;
"           to the 20th Column of the lines from 5 to 11
" Eg 2 :-   :7,10call MCCE(5, ' ', 26)
"           The above command will move the 5th Occurrence from the End of Character " " (white Space)
"           to the 26th Column of the lines from 7 to 10
    function! MCCE (num_occr, mv_char, col_num) range
        if (a:firstline <= a:lastline)
            nmap s 80i <ESC>
            let line_num = a:firstline
            while line_num <= a:lastline
                execute "normal " . line_num . "G$" . a:num_occr . "F" . a:mv_char . "s" . a:col_num . "|dw"
                let line_num = line_num + 1
            endwhile
            nunmap s
        else
            execute printf('ERROR : Start line %d is higher thatn End line %d, a:firstline, a:lastline)
        endif
    endfunction
```

Comment: I didn't test the function but I see `nmap s` and `nunmap s` it means that if I have `s` mapped I'll loose my mapping after executing the function, am I right? If I understood it correctly I think it would be interesting to save the mapping of use `80i` directly in the `execute` to avoid messing with the user configuration :-)

Comment: Thanks, this might be just me but I didn't understand much of that so I'm not sure how it'd work.

Comment: Hi statox, Yes you can use the 80i directly at the place of s, so no need of nmap s.

Hi Tim Abell, this will work surely..

Answer (score 2):

For what you've asked, there may be a simpler solution than employing alignment plugins. What you need is a text object for table cells:

For reference:
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html

```
onoremap ic :<c-u>normal! T\|vt\|<cr>                                                                                                                                                                             
onoremap ac :<c-u>normal! F\|vf\|<cr>
```

I noticed the `ic`, `ac` (mnemonic: inside cell, around cell) objects are free, but you can of course change them to `i|` `a|`.

Then for changing the content of a cell, just press `cic` or combine with whatever operator you need. (`dac` : delete a cell)

For completeness, i found a mapping useful which creates a separator row:

```
inoremap \|\| <Esc>kyyp:s/\v[^\|]/-/g<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

So that you can press || while starting a new row to copy the line above and essentially replace anything but pipes with a dash.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat trick, but when I run `cic` (change inside cell), it collapses the cell to zero chars wide and I have to manually re-pad it with spaces, which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Yea, for that re-aligning I would suggest to go with some existing alignment plugins. Eg https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular for an ex command :Tabularize /regex/l1<CR> which you can of course invoke by a mapping or https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align which provides a motion aware alignment operator (such as in `gaip*|` go aligned inside paragraph, split on every occurrence of `|`). However, assuming you really have the layout already, and just do not want to crash it, really just use Replace Mode (as invoked by `R`) when in appropriate position.

Comment: Why `vic` and `vac` don't work? Edit: it requires `vnoremap` instead.